# Removing the application published under alpha release in play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application published in plays store for production. I published an alpha release to the testers for testing the new update of the application. Now the testing is completed and i need to update the app. How to unpublish the app which is already in the alpha release.

I have checked the unpublish option in pricing & distribution under store presence. It will unpublish the entire app from play store. I don't want the production app to get removed, only the app release under alpha release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove it (and you can't probably). You just need to publish your app in production mode (with higher version code than the one in alpha mode), then the alpha's version will be unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

If  app  in Alpha means no one can downloaded it expect(access given to some mail ids) . if you don't want to view others means remove all mail ids.